# How to handle when a user clicks cancel?

Tags: angular, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have implemented the PasswordChange policy from the custom policy starter pack in Azure B2C.Which works fine when the user completes the change password flow, including redirecting back to the page in the angular application. Great.

however if the user clicks the cancel option in the B2C Change Password flow I get a runtime error in the angular application and I don't know how to handle this?

```
main.ts:6 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. 
URL Segment: 'login-failed'
Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'login-failed'
   at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.mjs:3656:16)
  at router.mjs:3638:28
  at catchError.js:10:39
```

and this other error:

```
core.mjs:8400 ERROR ServerError: access_denied: AADB2C90091: The user has cancelled 
entering self-asserted information.
Correlation ID: 931f36f0-640e-461b-84c0-3c4fa0ea04c0
Timestamp: 2023-11-03 03:24:59Z

at ResponseHandler.validateServerAuthorizationCodeResponse (ResponseHandler.mjs:76:19)
at AuthorizationCodeClient.handleFragmentResponse (AuthorizationCodeClient.mjs:83:25)
```

There doesn't seem a way to trap this error in the client, unlike the signup and sign in flow, where I can trap the error and do an appropriate redirct.

The code making the call:

```
  changePassword() {
    this.authService.loginRedirect({
    authority: environment.b2cPolicies.authorities.changePassword.authority,
    scopes: environment.apiConfig.scopes
   });
  }
```

The values from the environment are good, as they work when the user completes the change password. I just need to know what to do when the user clicks Cancel!

here is the code that handles cancel in the Sign-up and reset password flows:

```
    // Listen for error events
this.msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$
  .pipe(filter((msg: any) => msg.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_FAILURE),
    tap((msg: any) => {
      const error = msg.error as InteractionRequiredAuthError;
     
      if (error && error.errorMessage && error.errorMessage.includes('AADB2C90091')) {
         // Redirect to login page. User has cancelled self-asserted or change password.
         
        this.authService.instance.loginRedirect();
      }
      else if (error && error.errorMessage && 
         error.errorMessage.includes('AADB2C90118')) {
        // Trigger the Password Reset user journey
        this.authService.loginRedirect({
          authority: environment.b2cPolicies.authorities.resetPassword.authority,
          scopes: environment.apiConfig.scopes
        });
      }
    })
  )
  .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly I changed the error handling and removed the filter. It's now working! Thou I don't know why!

```
    // Listen for error events
this.msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$
  .pipe(
    tap((msg: any) => {
      const error = msg.error as InteractionRequiredAuthError; 
      if (error && error.errorMessage && error.errorMessage.includes('AADB2C90091')) {
         // Redirect: User has cancelled self-asserted or change password.  
        this.authService.instance.loginRedirect();
      }
      else if (error && error.errorMessage && error.errorMessage.includes('AADB2C90118')) {
        // Trigger the Password Reset user journey
        this.authService.loginRedirect({
          authority: 
          environment.b2cPolicies.authorities.resetPassword.authority,
          scopes: environment.apiConfig.scopes
        });
      }
    })
  )
  .subscribe();
```

This now seems to work with multiple tests and no regression in the signup sign in flow.

Works, but don't know why!